# A perl (or C) program to change password in Unix?

Tags: c, perl

hi i am trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714915/using-the-passwd-command-from-within-a-shell-script?lq=1) as mentioned in the answer using perl but it's not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$pipe="data";
$username="mukesh";
$password="mukesh";
open my $pipe, '|chpasswd' or die "can't open pipe: $!";
print {$pipe} "$username:$password";
close $pipe

[root@testgfs2 user_mgmt]# ./tess3.sh
Name "main::pipe" used only once: possible typo at ./tess3.sh line 2.
chpasswd: line 1: line too long
chpasswd: error detected, changes ignored
```

can any body suggest.whats wrong.

since --stdin is not avalable on all *nix i am trying to use this

**EDIT** : Is there any program in C to do this.cause that maigh be usefull for all versision if *nixes

Comment: Works for me as is. Maybe it's something with your version of `chpasswd`. Maybe it needs final `"\n"` at the end of input string, or maybe that "line too long" is about `/etc/shadow`, not your input. Does chpasswd work by itself, with `mukesh:mukesh` as input?

Comment: Why are you assigning a scalar value to $pipe and then trying to use it as a process handle?

Comment: @Ilion That's not the same `$pipe`, though he probably thinks it is. It is `$main::pipe`, and it still holds the string value it was assigned.

Comment: You can also think of `expect` script. but not sure about portability. The problem with `pipe` is that, some commands (e.g. ssh) may reject stdin redirected from pipe, when they are waiting for password.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this

```
system("$USERNAME:$PASSWORD | chpasswd");
```

[Based off this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4318265/777425)

Comment: did you mean `system("echo $USERNAME:$PASSWORD | chpasswd")`

Comment: Yes, I did. (only two years late)

Answer (score 0):

The code is okay as you've written it works fine for me. Try checking the quotes matching and I don't think it's necessary to have the file in.sh extension since you have #!/usr/bib/perl